# Is there a way to shorten when-else while using std_logic_vectors

Tags: vhdl

I'm writing a module and was wondering if there was a way to shorten all the lines I have to write while using when-else while the object that gets values is a std_logic_vector. I've created 2 types in my code, one for the status of the outputs and the other is an array of the former (I've got 6 modules, totaling in 18 different output configurations)

```
type    output_state is
    (
        red_indicator,
        green_indicator,
        open_drain_indicator,
        reset_indicator,
    );
    type    output_status_array is array (5 downto 0) of output_state;
```

now in the next code bracket ive inserted values to **output_status_array** by some logic:

```
            output_status_array(0) <= red_indicator when (sampled_data(0) > MAX_POWER_LEVEL) else open_drain_indicator when (sampled_data(0) < MIN_POWER_LEVEL) else green_indicator; -- todo : need to implement convert to integer before <\>
            output_status_array(1) <= red_indicator when (sampled_data(1) > MAX_POWER_LEVEL) else open_drain_indicator when (sampled_data(1) < MIN_POWER_LEVEL) else green_indicator;
            output_status_array(2) <= red_indicator when (sampled_data(2) > MAX_POWER_LEVEL) else open_drain_indicator when (sampled_data(2) < MIN_POWER_LEVEL) else green_indicator;
            output_status_array(3) <= red_indicator when (sampled_data(3) > MAX_POWER_LEVEL) else open_drain_indicator when (sampled_data(3) < MIN_POWER_LEVEL) else green_indicator;
            output_status_array(4) <= red_indicator when (sampled_data(4) > MAX_POWER_LEVEL) else open_drain_indicator when (sampled_data(4) < MIN_POWER_LEVEL) else green_indicator;
            output_status_array(5) <= red_indicator when (sampled_data(5) > MAX_POWER_LEVEL) else open_drain_indicator when (sampled_data(5) < MIN_POWER_LEVEL) else green_indicator;
```

I have 3 outputs for each given module, I could write a very long and tedious code indicating which values the outputs need to be, but I was wondering if there were some "bitwise" operations that the synthesizer does once I compile my code.

```
red_led_out             <=  '1' when output_status_array = red_indicator else '0';
green_led_out           <=  '1' when output_status_array = green_indicator else '0';
open_drain_out          <=  '1' when output_status_array = open_drain_indicator else '0';
```

**red_led_out**,**green_led_out** and **open_drain_out** are all std_logic_vectors, and I was wondering whether if for instance the only bits that will get a '1' in red_led_out will be the corresponding bits in the status_array which are set as **red_indicator**?
sorry for the long explanation, but I wanted to be very clear with what I wrote.

Comment: you only show snippets - please post a full example showing the problem

Comment: Unrelated questions presented here:  *Is there a way to shorten when-else while...* (in title), *but I was wondering if there were some "bitwise"...*, and *I was wondering whether if for instance the only bits...*.  Perhaps you can focus on one topic per question. Your 3rd snippet doesn't appear to be valid VHDL. `output_status_array` is a composite type (1st snippet) and not an object of it's element type `output_state`.  The second snippet right hand expressions in the conditional signal assignment statements appear ripe for replacement with function calls with a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly what you are doing without a full code listing. Perhaps you could consider using a generate loop:

```
status_gen : for i in 0 to 5 generate
    output_status_array(i) <= red_indicator when (sampled_data(i) > MAX_POWER_LEVEL) else open_drain_indicator when (sampled_data(i) < MIN_POWER_LEVEL) else green_indicator;
end generate;
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem, or provide more details about what is still not working.